# Problem with shopping cart, adding products, in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, shopping-cart

I have a problem with my shopping cart: when I want to add a product to the cart my function adds one product of each product available. (I hope this is clear enough since english is not my first language)

```
        <h3>Product list</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>
                {{plants.productName}} : {{plants.quantity}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br><br>    
    
    <div>
        <h3>Shopping list:</h3> 
        <ul>
        <li v-for="plant in plantList">
            {{plant.productName}} : {{stock}}
            <button @click="addPlant">Add {{plant.productName}}</button> 
            <!--<span v-if="plant.quantity === 0">No stock</span>
           -->
            
        </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
        
</div>
    <script>
    const app=new Vue({
        el: '#app', 
        data: {
            
            stock: 0,
            plantList:[
                {productName: 'flowers', quantity: 5},
                {productName: 'cactus', quantity: 3},
                {productName: 'trees', quantity: 6},
           ]
        }, 
        
        methods: {
            addPlant(){
           
            this.stock += 1;
            
            }
            
    })

</script>
```

I just want to add one product when I click the button

Comment: Can you show us the logic inside the method `addPlant()`? From what I see, when the user click on `add` button, that method is called, but none is passed as a product identifier, so I'm guessing the logic inside it can be wrong.

Comment: That is all I have in addPlant(), I have tried many methods but none of them worked, so I think that the logic is the problem too. // Eso es todo lo que tengo en el método addPlant; probé con varias lógicas distintas pero ninguna me funciona, y ahora ya estoy en blanco y no se me ocurre nada más. Gracias Luis por responderme, ¿se te ocurre alguna forma de que esto funcione?

Comment: What do you expect when the user clicks on button add? From my perspective, the value of `stock` is incremented by 1, nothing more. How do you add that product to the cart? I'm supposing there is some logic to call identify the product that was clicked, and then add it to the cart.

Comment: "How do you add that product to the cart?" I'm using the stock as the cart where I'm adding the products (this is just a simple homework for my js course), the problem is that I want to add just one unit of one product at a time when I click a button, but instead I'm getting three units, one per product, see the problem? "the value of stock is incremented by 1", that is what I want, but I want that the number is increased only in one of the products and not in three at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

When adding an item to the cart you need some way to specify the quantity to that specific item, the way it was implemented you are adding a quantity but not telling to which item.
To solve that, create an array to be the cart, and add the quantity in the cart associated with the product.

Also, when showing the quantity of each item, you must show it based on the item identity on the cart (in the example below, I' using the name as identity). That was the issue, you were showing the same value (`stock`) to all the items.

Here goes how it must be to work.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Product list</h1>

    <div>
        <h3>Shopping list:</h3> 
        <ul>
          <li v-for="plant in plantList">
              {{ plant.productName }} : {{ cart[plant.productName] }}
              <button @click="addPlant(plant)">Add {{plant.productName}}</button>
          </li>
        </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    cart: [], // holds the referente to each item and quantity
    plantList:[
        {productName: 'flowers', quantity: 5},
        {productName: 'cactus', quantity: 3},
        {productName: 'trees', quantity: 6},
   ]
  }),

  methods: {
    addPlant(plant){
      // if the item is in the cart, add +1 to item
      if(this.cart[plant.productName]) {
        this.cart[plant.productName] += 1
        return
      }

      // if the item is not in the cart, add it with 1 as quantity
      this.cart[plant.productName] = 1
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

[Live demo here](https://replit.com/@lcbrito/Add-Cart-Item#src/App.vue)

Comment: Wow that's awesome, it works exactly as I wanted. I'm just learning the logic of js so it's still very hard for me, so thank you so much for your help Luis.